# How to find a row and click a table element across the table with selenium?

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to click the link tied to the label for this td.

I can use the onclick to find one item link,but the name changes from HemoGlobin A1C, to HGB A1c, etc and the onclick has no unique ID to search for everytime.

using this now:

`WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//td[contains(@onclick, '%s' )]" % testname))).click()`

`testname = 'A1c'`

[image: UI]

[image: HTML]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```
testname= "a1c"
try:
    elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//td[contains(translate(text(), "AC", "ac"), {})]/following-sibling::td[3]//td'.format(testname))))
except TimeoutException:
    print("Element not found")
else:
    elem.click()
```

**Explanation:**

- `//td[contains(translate(text(), "AC", "ac"), testname)]`: First find a `td` element which contains `text` 'A1C' or 'A1c' (or 'a1C' or 'a1c'). Here `transalte()` is a xpath function which will replace all 'A' & 'C' with 'a' & 'c'.
- `/following-sibling::td[3]//td` Then we have to go to a sibling of that `td` element, which in your case is a third sibling of same type, and then we find the child element `td` in it.

Comment: This is clicking the 3rd TD which is correct, but it does not seem to be finding the A1C, and is always clicking the first entry. I thought because you had ac vs a1c, but after changing that I still get the first  row in the table, not the row with a1c.

Comment: @polishfreak, 1. Does the first row also has 'A1C'(case-insensitive) in the text in any `td` element? 2. Try this xpath `//td[contains(translate(text(), "AC", "ac"), "a1c")]` in the browser developer tools and see which element is found.

Comment: 1 no the test does not include the text a1c in any way. I will try that. if it helps the xpath to the a1c test name is `//*[@id="tOEOrdItem_ListTabularEMR"]/tbody/tr[4]/td[1]` I think this is the issue as the first items xpath is `//*[@id="tOEOrdItem_ListTabularEMR"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]`

Comment: This worked! ``//td[contains(translate(text(), "AC", "ac"), "a1c")]

Comment: Ok so just to confirm, have you tried my updated answer? I had a mistake originally, which was corrected in edit. I think that mistake could end up in first row.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one to check whether works.

```
testname = "A1c"
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//td[text()[contains(.,'" + testname + "')]]")))
element.click
```